# How to prove this integral inequality $\int_{ - 1}^1 {{{\left| {g\left( s \right)} \right|}^2}ds}$

Tags: solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, integral-inequality

**Question**
Let $g\in C_0^\infty((-1,1))$.Prove $\forall t\in (-1,1)$,$${g^4}\left( t \right) \le 16\int_{ - 1}^1 {\left( {{{\left| {g'\left( s \right)} \right|}^2} - \frac{{{g^2}\left( s \right)}}{{4{{\left( {1 - \left| s \right|} \right)}^2}}}} \right)ds} \cdot \int_{ - 1}^1 {{{\left| {g\left( s \right)} \right|}^2}ds} .$$

**Theorem.** Let $g \in C_0^\infty((-1,1))$. Then for all $t \in (-1,1)$,
$$g^4(t) \le 16 \int_{-1}^1 \left( |g'(s)|^2 - \frac{g^2(s)}{4(1 - |s|)^2} \right) ds \int_{-1}^1 |g(s)|^2 ds$$

**Proof.** Let $h(s) = g^2(s)$.
\begin{align*}
\left( \int_{-1}^1 \left( |g'(s)|^2 - \frac{g^2(s)}{4(1 - |s|)^2} \right) ds \right)^2 &\le \int_{-1}^1 ds \int_{-1}^1 |g'(s)|^4 - \frac{g^2(s) |g'(s)|^2}{2(1 - |s|)^2} ds \\
&= \int_{-1}^1 |g'(s)|^4 ds - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{g^2(s) |g'(s)|^2}{(1 - |s|)^2} ds \\
&\le \int_{-1}^1 |g'(s)|^4 ds - \frac{1}{2} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{g^4(s)}{(1 - |s|)^4} ds.
\end{align*}By the AM-GM inequality,
\begin{align*}
\frac{g^2(s) |g'(s)|^2}{(1 - |s|)^2} &\ge 4 \left( \frac{|g'(s)|}{2(1 - |s|)} \right)^4 \\
&= 4 \left( \frac{g^2(s)}{4(1 - |s|)^2} \right)^2 \\
&= \frac{g^4(s)}{(1 - |s|)^4}.
\end{align*}
$\int_{-1}^1 |g'(s)|^4 ds \le 2 \int_{-1}^1 g^4(s) ds$
\begin{align*}
$$\int_{-1}^1 g^4(s) ds \int_{-1}^1 |g(s)|^2 ds &\ge \left( \int_{-1}^1 g^2(s) ds \right)^2
&= h^2(-1) \\
&= g^4(-1).
\end{align*}Finally, by the AM-GM inequality,
$$\sqrt{2 g^4(-1) \int_{-1}^1 |g(s)|^2 ds} \le \sqrt{2} \sqrt{g^4(-1)} \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 |g(s)|^2 ds} = 2g^2(-1).$$